# Material ui performance issues with Card component

Tags: reactjs, performance, material-ui

I'm implementing React Beautiful Dnd with Material Ui, specially this case: https://react-beautiful-dnd.netlify.com/?path=/story/board--large-data-set

I have about 300 Material UI Card components in one view. I'm using React.Memo for optimizing changes. Rendering with 300 Material UI Cards takes about 5000ms versus rendering @emotion/styled components it take only 1000ms.

I tried to debug the issue, but looks like it's inside Material Ui. What makes it so heavy? Is there any better solutions?

Comment: Can you provide demo in codesandbox?

Comment: Yep, I can do it, just removing other references.

Comment: Hi, here is the demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-forest-c6wzl

Comment: I think that you have to use visualized scroll for a large data like this: https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized

Comment: Thanks. Need to check that one.

Comment: But still this is little bit confusing. I have implemented same with Jquery, and its much more faster with the same data? Is it because I get element by dom id? Not  updating by state.

Comment: Do you speak about  first render performance?

Comment: Yep, first rendering. And its also heavy when dragging elements, comparing to Jquery

Comment: Tested without material ui, and is was smooth.

Comment: Did you try to use mode:virtual: https://github.com/atlassian/react-beautiful-dnd/blob/master/docs/patterns/virtual-lists.md